# How to do a proper groupby query in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a table that holds multiple tracking id's in it. What I'm trying to do is group all tracking id's and get a count for them.

This is what the SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT tracking_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM tracking
GROUP BY tracking_id
```

I think I've found the correct method of doing this in django however I'm missing something and am currently getting the error `Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tracking_id'`

Here's what my view looks like:

```
def stats(request):

    users = Tracking.objects.values('tracking_id').annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id'))

    stats = []
    for user in users:
        stats.append((user.tracking_id, user.dcount))

    return render_to_response('tracking/stats.html', { 'stats': stats, })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about (partially inspired by @second's answer):

```
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id'))
```

and then

```
for user in users:
    stats.append((user[ 'tracking_id' ], user[ 'dcount' ]))
```

?

Comment: you can get the query to give you a list of tuples directly, by finishing with `.values_list('tracking_id', 'dcount')`

Answer (score 0):

for times like this, I would recommend trying out your code in a shell

`./manage.py shell` opens a python shell with your project code in the system path

```
>>> from myapp.models import Tracking
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> Tracking.objects.values('tracking_id').annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id'))

[{'tracking_id': 53, 'dcount': 12}, {'tracking_id': 1, 'dcount': 32}, ...]
```

this lets you see the format of the returned data and get you on your way

alternatively, you can add a pdb (python debugger) statement in your view code, (assuming `runserver` is serving your code), and load the page. when the pdb statement is reached, your server will stop and drop you into a debugger shell, right in the context of your view

```
def view(request):
    [...]
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace  # or even better, pip install ipdb and use instead

    return "foo"
```

Comment: do you mean `django-admin.py shell`? Any time I try `./manage.py shell` I get the error `-bash: ./manage.py: No such file or directory`

Comment: no. how are you launching your `runserver`? it may be `python manage.py shell`.