# Get count for objects

Tags: python, django

I want to get specialization count for all the doctors and want to show it in the admin panel

Here are the models

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)

class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

For instance, I want to show like:

Dermatologist: 10

Ophthalmologist: 15

I'm very new to Django and have no clue on how to go about it.

Comment: You can start with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621555/how-to-do-a-proper-groupby-query-in-django

Comment: dont you need to switch the order of your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `obj.doctor_set.count()` recipe. This method will be called for each Specialization record.

Use single SQL query with aggregation:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from app.models import Specialization

class SpecializationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['name', 'doctor_count_display']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SpecializationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(doctor_count=Count('doctor')).order_by('-doctor_count')

    def doctor_count_display(self, obj):
        return obj.doctor_count
    doctor_count_display.short_description = 'Number of doctors'
    doctor_count_display.admin_order_field = 'doctor_count'

admin.site.register(Specialization, SpecializationAdmin)
```

Comment: @catavarn thanks for the answer. Is there any way to show the list in descending order?

Comment: @JamesL. yes, you can order this list by aggregated field. I edited the answer. `order_by('-doctor_count')` was added for default ordering. And with `admin_order_field` property admin can change ordering to ascending/descending at any time.

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this in this way for example:

```
#admin.py
class SpecializationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_count',)
    def get_count(self, obj):
        return u"{}: {}".format(obj.name, obj.doctor_set.count())
    get_count.short_description = "Number of Doctors"
```

and register this like:

```
# also in admin.py
admin.site.register(Specialization, SpecializationAdmin)
```

dont forget to import `Specialization` model into `admin.py`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about queries [Django Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/)

To show the number of dermatologist:

```
Doctor.objects.filter(specialization__name="Dermatologist").count()
```

To show the number of ophthalmologist

```
Doctor.objects.filter(specialization__name="Ophthalmologist").count()
```